# C# XNet получение ответа на пост запрос

Tags: c#, post, xnet

Здравствуйте , есть Post запрос вида :

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
 {
     var multipartContent = new xNet.MultipartContent()
   {
     {new FileContent(@"C:\Users\Dream\Downloads\123.png"), "file1", "123.png"}
   };
     request.Post(uri, multipartContent).None();
 }
```

Как получить ответ от страницы куда я его отправил?

Comment: Точнее содержимое ответа от страницы

Answer (score 3):

скорее всего

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
 {
     var multipartContent = new xNet.MultipartContent()
   {
     {new FileContent(@"C:\Users\Dream\Downloads\123.png"), "file1", "123.png"}
   };
   string response = request.Post(uri, multipartContent).ToString();
 }
```

Кстати, зачем вы пользуетесь сторонней библиотекой? Стандартный `System.Net.WebClient` умеет закачивать файлы:

```
byte[] rawResponse = new WebClient().UploadFile(uri, @"C:\Users\Dream\Downloads\123.png");
string response = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(rawResponse);
```

зачем вам сомнительные сторонние велосипеды?

Comment: xNet используют когда влом\по незнанию - реализовывать поддержку прокси. Ну и сама либа не заброшена, сорцы открыты. Если что - всегда можно подправить.

Comment: @z668 только если ради поддержки socks5. документации нет, апдейтов за последние полтора года нет (кроме одного, в котором вообще непонятно что поменялось). судя по гитхабу - есть проблемы с отладкой и с кодировкой респонсов. imho, если нет необходимости работать через socks - то никакого смысла в ней нет.

Comment: Ну тут скорее дело просто в незнании\неумении сделать поддержку Socks 4\5. Да и нудно это для http\s. Для tcp проблем нет, можно ограничиться небольшим классом. Я досих пор не понимаю почему MS не сделают наконец то поддержку соксов для своего клиента. Да и приложение тут явно не промышленного масштаба. Либо школьное\вузовское задание, либо что то под социалки стоимостью 500 рублей максимум, либо вообще для себя.